# Scrapy error loop xpath

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have the follow html structure:

```
<div id="mod_imoveis_result">
    <a class="mod_res" href="#">
        <div id="g-img-imo">
            <div class="img_p_results">
                <img src="/img/image.jpg">
             </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is a product result page, so is `7` blocks for page with that `mod_imoveis_result` id. I need get image `src` from all blocks. Each page have 7 blocks like above.

I try:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "magichat"
    start_urls = ['https://magictest/results']

    def parse(self, response):
        for bimb in response.xpath('//div[@id="mod_imoveis_result"]'):
            yield {
                'img_url': bimb.xpath('//div[@id="g-img-imo"]/div[@class="img_p_results"]/img/@src').extract_first(),
                'text': bimb.css('#titulo_imovel::text').extract_first()
            }            
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "num_pages") and contains(@class, "pg_number_next")]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

I can't understand why `text` target is ok, but `img_url` get first result for all blocks for page. Example: each page have 7 blocks, so 7 texts and 7 img_urls, but, img_urls is the same for all other 6 blocks, and text is right, why?

If i change `extract_first` to `extract` i get others urls, but the result come in the same brackts. Example:

text: 1aaaa

img_url : a,b,c,d,e,f,g

but i need

text: 1aaaa

img_url: a

text: 2aaaa

img_url: b

What is wrong with that loop?

Comment: I solve that with `'img_url': bimb.xpath('./div[@id="g-img-imo"]/div[@class="img_p_results"]/img/@src').extract_first()`, but i can't understand why `./` solve that...

Answer (score 0):

**`//`** selects the root node i.e. `<div id="mod_imoveis_result">` of for node you're trying to get which is `div[@id="g-img-imo"]` so the two tage that were missed it the reason of *NO DATA*

**`.` **selects the current node which is mentioned in your xpath irrespective of how deep it is.

In your case `xpath('./div[@id="g-img-imo"]/div[@class="img_p_results"]/img/@src')` denotes selection from root node i.e. **from arrow**

```
 <div id="mod_imoveis_result">
    <a class="mod_res" href="#">

    ---> <div id="g-img-imo">

            <div class="img_p_results">   
               <img src="/img/image.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

I hope you i made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If all your classes have separate div names, in your case different class tag, then you can directly call image div and extract image URL.

```
//*[@class="img_p_results"]/img/@src
```